# How to register BroadcastReceiver for sms catcher?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing the application which must catch all input sms. For it I use SmsReceiver class which extends BroadcastReceiver class and it works, but I need that the application can work after rebooting automatically. For it I use the second BroadcastReceiver RebootingReceiver which extends BroadcastReceiver too, but I don't know how I can register SmsReceiver again. Please, I try to use this code, but it doesn't works:

```
public class RebootingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        context.registerReceiver(new SmsReceiver(), filter);
    }
}
```

Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".RebootingReceiver">
    <intent-filter >              
          <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: No, in this case RebootingReceiver will catch all new sms, but I need that RebootingReceiver only register SmsReceiver after rebooting again