# How to know that SMS has been sent or not , if i'm sending SMS via sms intent

Tags: android, sms

I have used this code to send `SMS`

```
String phoneNumber="000000000000";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber));
intent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsContent);
startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_CODE);
```

this will send `SMS` properly

But i had an issue on `onActivityResult()` ,the result code is always getting 0 , I don't know how to solve this issue,and How will i know that the `SMS` has been sent or not ?

then tried with `SmsSendObserver.SmsSendListener` interface to receive the callback.but it is giving an **error**

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider uri content://sms/ from pid=29471, uid=10277 requires android.permission.READ_SMS, or grantUriPermission()

and i can't give `READ_SMS` permission due to the google play permission policy update ,so how can i grant `URI` permission

Comment: You need to register your app with broadcast and need to listen actions of sms. For this a lot of answers already avaialble

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to registrate BroadcastReceiver for sms catcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664757/how-to-registrate-broadcastreceiver-for-sms-catcher)

Comment: "how can i grant URI permission" – You can't. That is something that the owner of the data would have to do. Considering Google's new restrictions, I believe your only options are to ensure that the user is using some SMS app that can relay that info to you somehow – which is likely completely infeasible – or to use an alternate method of sending, by which I mean, for example, Twilio, or some other such service.

Comment: I saw a lot of posts about android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED but
it's only for SMS receiving. i need to know how to detect SMS sending from the phone?

Comment: @MikeM. thank u for ur suggestion ,I'll  try with Twilio.